# invalid field found for struct test/entity.UserEntity's

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm really new to go and I decided to create a RestAPI for skill practising. So now I'm trying to make a one to many relationship between my **User** and **Book** entities. But when I try to save my **Book** entity to database, it shows me such error:

```
invalid field found for struct test/entity.UserEntity's field Books: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer
/Scanner interface
```

Here's my code:

**UserEntity**

```golang
type UserEntity struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string       `gorm:"unique;not null"`
    Email    string       `gorm:"unique;not null"`
    Password string       `gorm:"not null"`
    Books    []BookEntity `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}

func (*UserEntity) TableName() string {
    return "users"
}
```

**BookEntity**

```golang
type BookEntity struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string `gorm:"not null"`
    Isbn     int    `gorm:"unique;not null"`
    AuthorID uint
}

func (*BookEntity) TableName() string {
    return "books"
}
```

**BookAddModel**

```golang
type BookAddModel struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Isbn int    `json:"isbn"`
}

func (bookModel *BookAddModel) ToModel(ctx *gin.Context) {
    ctx.Bind(&bookModel)
}
```

Here's the code where I add entities to database

```golang
func AddBook(bookModel models.BookAddModel, author *entity.UserEntity) entity.BookEntity {
    var book entity.BookEntity
    mapstructure.Decode(bookModel, &book)
    config.DbSession.Create(&book) // <<<< here's error
    author.Books = append(author.Books, book)
    config.DbSession.Save(author)
    return book
}
```

**Config**

```golang
var DbSession *gorm.DB
var PostgresData = "host=localhost user=postgres password=4122 dbname=gorm port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
```

So what can bee the problem? If you know, please tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `foreignKey` for `UserEntity.Books`:

```
type UserEntity struct {
    ...
    Books    []BookEntity `gorm:"foreignKey:AuthorID,..."`
}
```

Just don't forget to drop tables first and rerun `AutoMigration`s:

```
    db.AutoMigrate(&UserEntity{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&BookEntity{})
```